# Convert array of dictionaries to dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

```
[
  [
    "firstname":"Gary","age":35,"lastname":"Jon","marks": 
      [
        "English":98,"Maths":45,"Science":58,"Social":95
      ],
    "section":"A"
  ], 
  [
    "firstname":"Jacob","age":32,"lastname":"bil","marks": 
      [
        "English":90,"Maths":65,"Science":88,"Social":90
      ],
    "section":"B"
  ]
]
```

How can I convert the above array of dictionaries into a dictionary combining the first and last name and total grades?
This is the expected result:

```
[Gary Jon: 296, Jacob bil: 333]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: As you haven't showed any attempt, I'm not going to add anything as an answer. But keep in mind that, if the data you have shown in the above is pretty much consistent, you can wrap your data to a `struct`. Then you can easily perform much complex calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
let d = [
    ["firstname":"Gary","age":35,"lastname":"Jon","marks":["English":98,"Maths":45,"Science":58,"Social":95],"section":"A"],
    ["firstname":"Jacob","age":32,"lastname":"bil","marks":["English":90,"Maths":65,"Science":88,"Social":90],"section":"B"]
]

let dd = d.reduce([:]) { (result, value) -> [String: Int] in
    let marks = value["marks"] as! [String: Int]
    let totalMarks = marks.values.reduce(0, +)

    let firstName = value["firstname"] as! String
    let lastName = value["lastname"] as! String

    let student = ["\(firstName) \(lastName)" : totalMarks]
    return result.merging(student) { $1 }
}
print(dd)
```

**Output**

> ```
> ["Gary Jon": 296, "Jacob bil": 333]
> ```

Comment: Good answer, however, you should handle those optionals better. Don't use any `!` if possible.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Agreed. I never recommend force unwrap in real production code. I would like to use a data structure to represent and manipulate above data easily. The above solution will also override the students with same name but this was just to show how an array of dictionaries can be reduced to a single dictionary.

Comment: I understand that your answer is intended more like a proof-of-concept solution, but given the OP's post, I'm guessing their experience in Swift (or programming in general even) isn't very high and so they might just use exactly what you've posted here, rather than replicating your logic with an own, safe implementation.

Comment: While this answer is correct it is not very helpful without a description on what it does how it answer the question. Bare in mind that answers are not only for OP but also for future readers how might be looking for solution to a similar problem.